# horizontal offset for scrollviewer in gridview C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012), Is there any way to scroll grid view horizontal scroll bar by providing HorizantalOffset.
**Brief:**  In scroll-viewer class we can move horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar dynamically using `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` and `ScrollToVerticalOffset`,But in gridview I don't find those properties, So how can I scroll dynamically by code? or can i get reference to scrollbar in gridview ? Can any one help me with this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the reference to the ScrollViewer from the GridView's template using VisualTreeHelper. You can also use some helper methods I put in [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) - in [VisualTreeHelperExtensions](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16916#309178). You would just need to add

```
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Extensions;
```

then call

```
var scrollViewer = myGridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>()
```

and there you go.

EDIT* - note the namespace has changed in later versions of the toolkit to WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions.