# Using Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate and Binding Canvas.Top doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, itemcontainerstyle

First of all I am coding a Windows Store app for Windows 8 with C# and XAML.
I am using a `GridView` to display a grouped Collection of Objects.
Each group is displayed as a single column where the associated items are shown.

This works fine but I want the `ItemsPanel` of each column to be a `Canvas` Panel.

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Now I set `Canvas.Top` to a static number right in xaml. This works like expected.

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="50" />
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But if i use databinding it does not work.

```
<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Distance}" />
```

Does binding not Work on Styles and Setters in Windows 8 Store App Development with Visual Studio 2012?
How can i fix this that i can set the Canvas.Top dynamically for each Item from a property?

Answer (score 1):

Binding in style setters are not supported in WinRT, similarly to Silverlight before version 5. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857505/how-do-i-do-bindings-in-itemcontainerstyle-in-winrt) which also relates to binding in `ItemContainerStyle` (a workaround is suggested with some attached properties).

Alternatively you can set the property value/binding in code when the item container is generated - subclass the `GridView` and override something like [ItemsControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) to set bindings from the item container to model item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems binding the property in Styles to the ViewModel isn't available.
Canvas.Top is a kind of attached-property. 
If you want to dynamically change each item's property of `Canvas.Top`, [you can do it in code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11831975/1613961). 
Extract out each `GridViewItem`'s `Canvas` and then set its Top property.