# WinRT gridview scroll detection

Tags: gridview, scroll, windows-runtime

on WinRT, I have a gridview. I want to execute a method when the end of the gridview is reached.

However, there is no event method like that for a gridview.

I try to detect a manipulation of the gridview, but seems the scrollviewer included in my gridview catch all the events. How can I get this scrollviewer ? And even after, with my scrollViewer, how can i know the position of this scrollviewer (reachedEnd for example ?)

Thanks

Comment: What do you need this for? If it is to load new items when the user reaches the end, you should instead have your collection implement ISupportIncrementalLoading. If you do this, the grid will incrementally and automatically load your data. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx

Comment: because my app use a crossplatform core, I can't use something like ISupportIncrementalLoading (because depending of Windows UI). I forget to mention it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` to find a descendant of the `GridView` of type `ScrollViewer`, then subscribe to its `ViewChanged` event. In the event handler you can detect where you are in the `ScrollViewer`. You would then compare the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrollablewidth.aspx) with `HorizontalOffset` to see if you have reached the end.

Use it if you want to drive some custom layout/animation logic, but do use `ISupportIncrementalLoading` though as chue x suggested if what you are trying to do is load more data.

Comment: Thank a lot, the problem is my gridview have only 1 child after the loading, a border. In Xaml, I use only a gridview, but this gridview have a scroll ... seems the gridview have an intern scroll and can't access to it. Finally I success this by using that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830574/horizontal-offset-for-scrollviewer-in-gridview-c-sharp  and it works :-)